# Hide a table column with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, hide

I have the following table:

```
<table id="btt-ranges" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"> </th>
            <th id="Business" scope="col">Type of Business</th>
            <th id="Ranges" scope="col"> Ranges</th>
            <th scope="col">BTT</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Example</td>
            <td>Example</td>
            <td>Example</td>
            <td>Example</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Example</td>
            <td>Example</td>
            <td>Example</td>
            <td>Example</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Example</td>
            <td>Example</td>
            <td>Example</td>
            <td>Example</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I have to do is hide the last column, but I can't change how the table is right now.
I can use Javascript and so far this is what I tried:

```
function show_hide_column() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('btt-changes');
    var rows = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    for (var row = 0; row < rows.length; row++) {
        var cols = rows[row].children;
        console.log(1, cols.length);
        if (4 >= 0 && 4 < cols.length) {
            var cell = cols[4];
            console.log(cell, cell.tagName);
            if (cell.tagName == 'TD') cell.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do without touching the table?

Comment: You can use css selector to select the last td like using "td:last-child"

Comment: You can replace some expressions by boolean value. For example 4 >= 0 you can replace by true. 4 is everytime more (or equal) than 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code selects the col's cells (th and tds), and then hides them ([fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cfa1y541/1/)):

```
var lastColHeader = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('th:last-child', '#btt-ranges'), 0); // get the header cell
var lastColCells = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('td:last-child', '#btt-ranges'), 0).concat(lastColHeader); // get the column cells, and add header

lastColCells.forEach(function(cell) { // iterate and hide
    cell.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience, I'm new to all this :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use javascript for this. You can use a CSS selector to hide the last column:

```
#btt-ranges tr td:last-child { display: none; }
```

Edit: Just realized you specifically need to do it in javascript. Not sure if there is any way to append a style without touching the table.

Comment: Yeah, only Javascript, but thans for your support :)

Comment: Your answer was very helpful to me. Glad you posted it.